# OpenCV imshow over ssh: run script on remote host, send output to local host

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ssh

I'm running a python script on a remote computer's terminal after ssh-ing into it.

The script has a few `cv2.imshow()` statements in it that open up windows on the remote host.
I would like these windows to open on the local host.

I have tried using X forwarding (`ssh -X host`) but that does not solve my problem.
(I confirmed X forwarding works by running gedit and nautilus)

PS: Both remote and local hosts have Ubuntu 14.04 if that matters.

Comment: Is your OpenCV built with X11 backend or Qt or something else?

Comment: Is workaround about saving and downloading result as image acceptable for you?

Comment: @outoftime no, I thought of this but it would be too impractical for my particular purpose. Cheers.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm not sure, but I think I built it without Qt support. Ideas on how to check this? Anyway, how would this affect a potential solution?